# Quartz Scheduler Job Sequence/Workflow

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to execute a series of jobs where one job execute other two, and one of the two execute another.

```
Job 1 --> Job 3
      --> Job 2 -->Job 4
```

The jobs are for sending data from db.
This is what i have done

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class MembersJob implements Job{
    List<Member>unsentMem=new ArrayList<Member>();
    JSONArray customerJson = new JSONArray();
    Depot depot;

    public MembersJob(){
        depot = new UserHandler().getDepot();
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
        if ( Util.getStatus() ){

            runSucceedingJobs(jec);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No internet connection");
        }

    }

  public void runSucceedingJobs(JobExecutionContext context){
      JobDataMap jobDataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
      Object milkCollectionJobObj = jobDataMap.get("milkCollectionJob");
      MilkCollectionsJob milkCollectionsJob = (MilkCollectionsJob)milkCollectionJobObj;

      Object productsJobObj = jobDataMap.get("milkCollectionJob");
      ProductsJob productsJob = (ProductsJob)productsJobObj;
    try {
        milkCollectionsJob.execute(context);
        productsJob.execute(context);
    } catch (JobExecutionException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error...");
        Logger.getLogger(MembersJob.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Call jobs in series

```
//Members Job
    JobKey membersJobKey = new JobKey("salesJob", "group1");
    JobDetail membersJob = JobBuilder.newJob(MembersJob.class)
    .withIdentity(membersJobKey).build();
    membersJob.getJobDataMap().put("milkCollectionJob", new MilkCollectionsJob());
    membersJob.getJobDataMap().put("productsJob", new ProductsJob());

    //
    CronTrigger membersTrigger =  newTrigger()
                                .withIdentity("salesTrigger", "group1")
                                .withSchedule(
                                        cronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ?"))
                                .forJob(membersJobKey)
                                .build();

    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(membersJob, membersTrigger);
    scheduler.start();
```

The problem is members job starts but does not start other jobs when it is done. What is the easiest and fastest way to achieve this?